# Inside “sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf” after inserting “Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf ”.When I enter this in “sudo apache2ctl restart”

Tags: phpmyadmin

This is the code inside editor:

```
 <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all denied
    </Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess
#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect parti>
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommend>
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent>
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" >
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf:w
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
ServerName 127.0.0.1

Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

[Fri Jun 11 21:12:06.484390 2021] [alias:warn] [pid 23171] AH00671: The Alias directive in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf at line 3 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.

The above error is displayed in the terminal.

Can someone help me to solve this error.

Comment: You maybe using a directive that you have already used previously as the base path in your phpmyadmin/apache.conf file. Please share the phpmyadmin/apache.conf too for more clarity.

Comment: @Kavish Baghel  I refered a youtube tuturial to download & install apache,php,mysql,phpmyadmin.So can you tell me where can i find the phpmyadmin/apache.conf

Comment: The file should be on the same path that you added i.e /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

Answer (score 0):

First, you've twice placed the same directive: `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` appears twice in your pasted file. You should really only need it once.

However, a more glaring problem here is that you shouldn't have to do this at all. You must be using the packaged version (based on the paths and file names you reference), installed through apt or dpkg or yum or some such, in which case the package manager should be changing all the configuration for you and you shouldn't need to manually edit anything. You should revert your changes and try to reinstall/reconfigure the phpMyAdmin package, then if you still have trouble post the exact problem you're experiencing.